# how do I get a string to be recognised as my variable

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame
number=1
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1080))#,pygame.FULLSCREEN)
app1=pygame.image.load("moonlight.jpg").convert()
app2=pygame.image.load("youtube.jpg").convert()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    if number==1:
        screen.blit("app"+str(number), (-100,0))
    clock.tick(40)
    pygame.display.update()``
```

How do I get `"app"+str(number)` to be recognised as the `app1` variable.

I get the error `"argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str"`

Comment: You need to get a variable by name. You can do it like this: `locals().get('app1', None)`

Comment: While it is possible to access a variable using a string holding its name, the fact that you want to do so is an indication that you should be using a dictionary rather than separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier, try doing something like this:

```
    while True:
        if number == 1:
            screen.blit(app1, (-100,0))
        elif number == 2:
            screen.blit(app2, (x coordinates, y coordinates))
        clock.tick(40)
        pygame.display.update()
```

This way, you won't have to deal with conflicting variable types. Also using this method, your code will become more compact.